# Accessing databases via. adb shell

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

In the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite), it's mentioned that `sqlite3` is available via the adb shell.  However, when I do this, the database I am looking at appears completely empty, whereas when I `adb pull` the `.sqlite` file and examine it locally, it contains what it should.  For example, in the latter case `.tables` lists the tables, in the former case it lists nothing, and attempts to `select` from the tables that should exist return "Error: no such table".  Etc.

There is no permissions issue -- `sqlite3` starts without complaint, I am apparently root and the permissions are 660.

Comment: How exactly are you running `sqlite3` with the `adb` shell?

Comment: @CL According to [this official-but-casual description](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#shellcommands), the `adb shell` is a unix-y remote shell, hence can accesses binaries in the device's `/system/bin`.  However, in the case of `sqlite3` I'm guessing it's using a local version on the remote file, since A) I don't see `sqlite3` in the device's `/system/bin`, and B) the android SDK includes a copy of `sqlite3` in the `tools/` directory.

Comment: What exactly are you typing to run `sqlite3`?

Comment: @CL Sorry, lol, my eyes read that as *"Why exactly are you trying to run `sqlite3`?"* yesterday.  **And thanks,** because that lead to my problem, of course: `sqlite3` creates a file if the path doesn't exist.  I must have been one level up (`/data/data/[app]/` instead of `/data/data/[app]/databases`) when I first went in and subsequently kept taking that for what I was looking for...facepalm.

Answer (score 2):

In fear that someone may someday make the same stupid mistake: beware that if the filepath you use with `sqlite3` does not exist, it will be created on the presumption that you are making a new database.

Evidently I logged in, `cd`'d to `/data/data/[app]` -- which I could see in the android device monitor's "File Explorer" contained `database/[app].sqlite` -- forgot to `cd database` and did not bother to `ls` because I was (sort of subconsciously) presuming `sqlite3` would give a "File not found" error if it wasn't there.  This creates an empty `[app].sqlite` file which is what I subsequently kept finding nothing in.